# Is it possible to intercept the "typeof" operation with an ES2016 Proxy?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to define a handler property that intercepts `typeof proxyObject`? None of the listed traps at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler) list it as an interception.

Comment: Why would you do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to intercept `typeof`. The type of the proxy object will be the same as the proxy target.

You can see this in the spec here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation with the important parts of the table being

1. Object (ordinary and does not implement [[Call]]) => "object"
2. Object (implements [[Call]]) => "function"

A proxy is an object, and whether it implements `[[Call]]` depends on the type of `target` passed to the proxy at creation time. That you can see in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-proxycreate Step 7. So if you pass it a function (they all implement `[[Call]]`), then the proxy will too, and the proxy will return `function` for `typeof`.

Comment: Does that apply to `instanceof` ?

Comment: @MyUserInStackOverflow You don't need proxy for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance

Comment: Oh great ! didn't realize it was related to instanceof operator.

Comment: `instanceof` can be intercepted via `getPrototypeOf` handler